# AngularJS set a delay between http requests

Tags: angularjs, http

Hello I am quite new to angularjs and I working on an app that downloads files from an API.
The files are downloaded to the server and then served on the client side. It is working but the second file is not fully downloaded ie. the file size is smaller than the one on the server. (The file has already been converted to xml before, in case you wonder about the json part). My guess is that there is a timing issue where the file downloaded on the client side is been downloaded too soon? I wonder whether the best solution is to add a delay so that it gives the downloading of the file some more time? But I don't know enough angular to know. If anyone has suggestions I would be very grateful. Thank you.

Here's the code in controller:

```
    $scope.download = function() {
        // first file
        $http.get("http://localhost:3000/downloadFile")
        .then(function(results) {
        // second file
       $http.get("http://localhost:3000/downloadComplete")
         .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.toJSON = '';
                $scope.toJSON = angular.toJson(data);
                var blob = new Blob([data], { type:"application/json;charset=utf-8" });           
                var downloadLink = angular.element('<a></a>');
                            downloadLink.attr('href',window.URL.createObjectURL(blob));
                            downloadLink.attr('download', $scope.fileDownload);
                downloadLink[0].click();

            });

       });

};
```

Comment: Did you try with another file ? I don't understand why you specify `.xml` for your file but your mime-type is `application/json`

Comment: I don't think it is because of delay, could be some other part of the program is interfering with this, cannot comment about it without more details, either way, add a delay and check it out........     syntax is --- >
setTimeout(function() {
//do something
}, no_of_milliseconds );

Comment: Hello Fieldset, thanks for your comment. Yes I've tried with many files, I've been trying to sort this out for 3 days now ;(. I changed the mime-type, but it doesn't seem to make a difference with xml so Ieft it as json. The file is outputted in the correct format, just not fully downloaded...

Comment: Thank you swordfish12 - that was my first thought, but like you say it could something else interfering. Should I place the timeout just after the  $http.get("http://localhost:3000/downloadFile")
        .then(function(results) {

Comment: Swordfish12 it was a timing difference- the file just needed a little more time.